# Changing the order of elements in a ready-to-use WordPress template

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using a WordPress template ([WP Clear by Solostream](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www.solostream.com/wordpress-themes/wp-clear/&ei=e1ANT8vtOdDsOcD_0LoH&usg=AFQjCNGYLTD6wKlBbK5Z7L-OjGkE_AzMuw)) that comes with a top navigation bar above the header and would like to place it below the header.

From what I read I understood that there's no way to edit the HTML of a WP template, and I'm wondering how I should I go about that.

Please have mercy, I'm a WP newbie.

Thanks, 
Iddo

Answer (score 0):

For altering the appearance of a WP themes you have to alter the css or the html (mixed with php) of that theme. Some themes have options you can alter in the wp-admin interface. It depends on the theme, in which way you are able to alter the appearance via options.

If there are no options for switching positions of the navigation bar and the header (it is unlikely that there are options for that), you have to alter the html.

You will find the html on the server in the folder wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME-NAME. The html for your case would be most likely in the file header.php.